# Android Sliding Tab

Tags: android, tabs, sliding

I am a newbie of Android development. I want to implement a sliding tabhost with animation. The effect is shown in the following video: http://youtu.be/XuLQmXLDrJQ 
This app comes from HTC Sense clock. You can focus on the bottom of the screen. My question is that how to impelment the switch effect of icons at the bottom of this app.  Is this app implemented with tab, scrollview or viewflipper?

Answer (score 0):

I am sure that it's not tabs, I see it like this...

1. A stationary horizontal scrollview that recives touch events
2. A travelling top that can be any layout.

The touch information is passed from 1 to 2 , this will tell 2 which colored image to display.

The transition animations on 2 would need to be fine tuned but look like standard android animations.

you might find the study of this code useful.[View flow](https://github.com/pakerfeldt/android-viewflow)

I hope it helps..

Comment: 2. option would be better(at least easier once programmer understands the usage of Android Fragments), if @Nero uses android.support.v4.view.ViewPager class from android v4 support library instead of any layout.